# MAUI BoxView unable to set Background Color

Tags: xaml, xamarin, maui

With .Net MAUI I created a BoxView and am unable to change the Background Color... it remains Black regardless of what color I set.  Both Windows and Android Emulator display the same.  Any ideas?  Thanks!

[Screenshot of XAML + App](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1pJZd.jpg)

Comment: please do not post code as images

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please replace following property:

```
BackgroundColor="SteelBlue"
```

with

```
Color="SteelBlue"
```

Comment: What is BackgroundColor for?

Comment: Apparently nothing